# How to store future dates for scheduling in mongoDB considering daylight saving times

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, datetime

Here is my scenario

my API takes a local datetime which is the latest time users (in the same region) can submit their work.

I want to save the datetime in local time along with timezone, that way I can apply the timezone offset to convert to UTC before sending the date to the client. This should work even if the DST changes after saving the date.

But MongoDB only saves the dates in UTC format at least in with java-mongo where it converts the local time to UTC before saving to the database. I am not able to store my date without converting it first to UTC.

So, my second approach is to get the local date from request convert it into UTC based on timeZone information that I already have. This approach would work fine unless in a scenario where daylight saving hours changed after saving the date but before that date expired.

e.g. local date got from the client is `2020-03-28 00:00` who is in +4 UTC. I convert it to UTC and stores it as `2020-03-28T20:00:00Z`. But if the daylight saving changes within that period the users can get one more hour to submit their work.

So, my question is how can I handle such a scenario if I store the date in UTC, or suggest something else.

Comment: UTC is a time standard which is constant - it does not have daylight saving time (DST). Since all time-zones are expressed relative to UTC (with or without DST) the scenario you are worried about does not exist (and is exactly why UTC exists). You can read more about UTC on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Comment: Maybe, I didn't explain my question properly. Actually, this is to allow a user to submit or not. if I assign a task to some users and say they have to complete it by 8:00 PM MY LOCAL TIME and after some days there is a daylight saving in place the validation could be off.

Comment: I still don't think I understand the problem. You set `2020-03-28 00:00` which is in a +4 UTC zone as an expiry date - that gets converted to `2020-03-27T20:00:00Z`. Now, when your user in a different timezone submits their assignment, you take the time `2020-03-28 00:00` which is in a +3 UTC zone - that gets converted to `2020-03-27T21:00:00Z`. Your validation will see the that the second UTC time is past than the expiry date and therefore not valid.

Comment: And if you mean the creator will just say "I want it submitted by 20:00" and never gives you a date - how will you know which day at 20:00 they mean? Presumably you always have a date (whether submitted by the creator or by some kind of hard coded rule) which means you can successfully use UTC

Comment: of course there will be a date, my problem is very similar to what has been mentioned here
http://www.creativedeletion.com/2015/03/19/persisting_future_datetimes.html

Comment: You are looking at a very specific problem here that will very rarely happen - countries do not just make significant changes to their time-zones on a whim. If I were you, I would find a decent library that handles this kind of stuff for you and keep it updated.

Answer (score 1):

In the MongoDB, you can store both the current date and the current client’s offset from UTC. You can directly insert or update from the client, you will store a timestamp based on the user's clock though still be stored as UTC along with the current client offset from the UTC. You can reconstruct the original local time by applying the saved offset:

[MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/model-time-data/)

> MongoDB stores times in UTC by default, and will convert any local time representations into this form. Applications that must operate or report on some unmodified local time value may store the time zone alongside the UTC timestamp, and compute the original local time in their application logic.